# Not able to build my first Default Xamarin Form android project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am new to mobile development. The error I am getting in xamarin but I have a feeling this is not specific to xamarin but related to android sdk

I tried to set this up in Visual Studio 2015. I followed all the steps on xamarin website. Can someone help me in finding and fixing this issue.

Trying to Create a Xamarin Form portable app. And getting errors in Droid project.

1. Nothing modifying and building with defaults gives me:

---

```
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Platform.V11.AppCompat'.   App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v14\values-v14.xml  15  
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Platform.V11.AppCompat.Light'. App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v14\values-v14.xml  21  
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.  App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml  131 
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.    App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml  182 
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat'. App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml  11  
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V22.Theme.AppCompat.Light'.   App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml  17
```

========================================================================

2. Changing "Compile Using Android Version" to Android5.0 gives me:

---

```
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Platform.V11.AppCompat'.   App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v14\values-v14.xml  15  
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Platform.V11.AppCompat.Light'. App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v14\values-v14.xml  21  
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Dialog'.  App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml  131 
Error       Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Base.V11.Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog'.    App2.Droid  \App2.Droid\obj\Debug\resourcecache\B237B8541B965BBE5CA1DD64CF2395A7\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml  182
```

My default package.config looks like:

```
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.0.1.3" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.0.0.6482" targetFramework="monoandroid60" />
```

Updated to latest stable Xamarin.Forms 2.1.0.6529 gives me same errors.

### My SDK Manager looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: What minimum and target API levels are you using?

Comment: Both same. I tried with minimum and target both as api21 and then with both as 23.

Comment: Im having this issue also. Did you fix it?

Comment: I was managed to make it working using this thread: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/53748/resource-designer-cs-no-definition ::
1. Uninstall all Xamarin packages using nuget ("force uninstall" and "remove dependencies" set to true),
2. Clean project
3. Update Target SDK to API level 23
4. Install latest Xamarin.Forms from nuget

These steps allowed 2 projects to be successfully updated

Answer (score 1):

You may find an answer here:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/46840/error-retrieving-parent-for-item-no-resource-found-that-matches-given-name

You are correct, that seems related to droid sdk.
Excerpt from the mentioned page:
"Fixed it. Turns out enough uninstalling and reinstalling of components and SDKs fixed it. (was a corrupt AppCompat V7 file)"